# Where am I going wrong in creating an R studio server

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I firstly create an instance...

[image]

Secondly I select Ubuntu

[image]

I choose the free tier and click configure instance details...

[image]

I then configure these settings in the following way (where PhD is the VPC I created):

[image]

I add the following code to the asvanced description to install r studio

[image]

I add some storage

[image]

I don`t bother adding any tags.

[image]

Final review page looks like

[image]

Choose my key pair
[image]

However I cannot log in to Rstudio...
[image]

I have tried the ip:8787, ip:80 etc. with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I get this output

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-175:~$ netstat -tnlp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, but probably it's the Network ACL.

There are two types of "firewalls" in AWS. One is Security Groups, which is attached to a network interface (which usually means it's attached to the instance). The other type is Network ACLs, which are attached to the subnet. Both must allow access. You'll find Network ACLs under VPC. Note those are stateless firewalls, meaning you have to open access for both incoming and outgoing packets, unlike Security Groups.

The other obvious problem might be that the R server didn't start, or didn't start on the port you're expecting it to. Ssh to the instance and check the output of `netstat -tnlp`. `t` means list TCP connections, `n` means do not resolve names, `l` means list only listening ports, and `p` means show process listening on port. `p` needs root access.

Edit: According to your netstat output, R-Studio isn't started. It looks like you installed R-Studio, but you didn't install R. Check [the documentation](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/). Specifically, the part that says "RStudio requires a previous installation of R version 3.0.1 or higher".

To check why it doesn't start, ssh to the instance and run `sudo rstudio-server start` manually, see what error you get. If you don't get anything on the console, check the log files. You can also try `sudo rstudio-server verify-installation`.

Comment: I added the output for the `netstat` you suggested.

Comment: I re-created the instance exactly as above and I add a user / password part `useradd MYUSER
echo MYUSER:MYPASS | chpasswd` and it somehow worked... but when I go to log into Rstudio I get the `unable to connect to service`...